# Install Package on Previous Version of Ubuntu

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, dbus

I need to install a package (in this case it is [dbus-broker](https://github.com/bus1/dbus-broker)) on Ubuntu 20.04 (focal). Unfortunately `apt install dbus-broker` does not do the trick because [the package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/dbus-broker) is currently only available for hirsute (21.04).

**This seems like it is probably a common problem which makes me think there is likely a common solution too.** Can someone shed some light on what that could be?

Comment: What you are trying to do is called *backporting*. Sometimes it works, sometimes it does not work. Generally, if you find yourself needing to bolt newer software onto an older LTS release, it means that LTS release is not meeting your needs anymore. Consider using a newer release of Ubuntu instead that requires no haywiring.

Comment: If you have to install it into 20.04 the git install process for that isn't that difficult to do.  As far as the required packages go, the `linux-api-headers` can be ignored if you already have the kernel headers installed.  Also, it does require `libsystemd-dev` to install.

Comment: @user535733 Thanks for the term! That's definitely helpful. I can't use a newer release because the base image I am building upon still uses the older release.

Comment: @Terrance So if I understand correctly, what you are saying is building from source is my best bet?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I just did to see if it worked.  It installed just fine into my 20.04 installation.

Comment: @Terrance Awesome, thanks for taking the time to do that!

Comment: You can download the .deb file from packages.ubuntu.com and install it in the older version of Ubuntu (if all the dependencies are available).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, for the https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/dbus-broker the dependencies would all need to be upgraded as well for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.  So, it is best to install from the git source

From the [git](https://github.com/bus1/dbus-broker) to install:

First install the prereqs:

*More than likely you already have the `linux-headers` installed, so we are going to skip that. However, the `libsystemd-dev` will be requested during the build.*

```
sudo apt install git ninja-build meson pkg-config python-docutils libsystemd-dev
```

Next, download the git source for `dbus-broker` and enter the newly created folder:

```
git clone https://github.com/bus1/dbus-broker
cd dbus-broker/
```

Create a build dir and enter it:

```
mkdir build
cd build/
```

Now, build and install the `dbus-broker`:

```
meson setup . ..
ninja
ninja test
ninja install
```

Hope this helps!